# getting width of element including pseudo element children

Tags: javascript, width, pseudo-element

I have something like that:

```
//sass
.icon {
   padding: 5px;
   &:after {
     content: '#';
   }
 }

 //html
 <div class="icon"></div>

 //js (onload)
 const w = document.querySelector('.icon').getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

The result (`w`) is less than what chrome developer tools tell me. I guess that is because of the pseudo element (`:after`). Is there a way to get the full/real width of the element?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the comments I could find the bug: the css isn't present when the query happens.

Comment: seems to work fine for me - https://jsfiddle.net/402e0te6/ (I have also tried without the inline-block) - my console logs 18 and chrome dev tools says the div is 18px - 10 padding plus 8 for the #

Comment: this seems to work fine for me too , try to run your JS code  using  timeout , may be your CSS takes some time to load

Comment: thanks for testing! The css is indeed not loaded at that point.